# Doubt on norm of the Sobolev space $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

If I consider the Sobolev space $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ I have the norm 
$$\Vert u\Vert_{H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}=\bigg(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq 2}\Vert D^\alpha u\Vert^2_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}\bigg)^\frac{1}{2}.$$
Is this norm is equivalent to
$$\Vert u\Vert=\left(\Vert u\Vert_{L^2}^2+\Vert\Delta u\Vert_{L^2}^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}?$$
In this way if I have to show that a function is in $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ it suffices to study the function and its Laplacian,doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write:
$$\Vert u\Vert=\left(\Vert u\Vert_{L^2}^2+\Vert\Delta u\Vert_{L^2}^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
Then the two norms are equivalent. You can see this by either using interpolation inequalities or by going to the Fourier transform where the estimates are easy:
$$\Vert u\Vert_{H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}=\bigg(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq 2}\Vert |\xi^{\alpha}|\hat u\Vert^2_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}\bigg)^\frac{1}{2}$$
and 
$$\Vert u\Vert=\left(\Vert \hat u\Vert_{L^2}^2+\Vert |\xi|^2 \hat u\Vert_{L^2}^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Comment: Yes I forgot the square in my question. So in this way when I have to verify that a function is in $H^2$ I can ignore the derivative of order $1$ and just verify that $f$ anf $\Delta f$ are in $L^2$.

Comment: Peter Michor's suggestion is correct, but you might want to check Gårding's inequality for a possibly even easier argument.

Comment: Does this holds on bounded domains?

Comment: @Afonso yes, provided either  the boundary is $C^{1,1}$ or the domain is convex.

Comment: @username any reference?

Comment: @Migalobe For example [here, page 59](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/pluginfile.php/73229/mod_resource/content/0/Lecture%20notes%202017.pdf).